# Free software to draw UML interaction overview diagrams

Tags: uml

I'm looking for a free software to draw [UML interaction overview diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_overview_diagram). Free as in speech would be preferred, but free as in beer will do fine as well.

Comment: have a look at plantuml and see what it can do for you (http://plantuml.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately PlantUML does not support interaction overview diagrams, but I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Papyrus](https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) supports UML interaction overview diagrams and is free as in speech.